# Is it possible to create a template for the wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to use a Wiki page library. Only a wiki page is empty and contains no template!
Is it possible to create my own html-page and use it as a template for the wiki pages.
Or are there perhaps other options. And are there some examples on the internet.

Gr. P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to site settings -> Site content types under Web Designer Galleries -> Wiki page -> Advanced settings -> Document Template, upload a new document template -> Set Update Sites and Lists as Yes.

After that, when you go to site pages library, add a new wiki page. The new wiki page with custom template.